# How to type response from jwt.decode ()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jwt

I am using React app and using my JWT information recorded in my localstorage. The problem is that in Typescipt, I can't access my object's response, even if I put an interface.

Where am I going wrong?

This is my code:

```
// auth.ts

import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
...

export const getUser = () => {

    const tokenBearer = getToken();
    const hashToken = tokenBearer ? tokenBearer.split(' ') : false;
    
    if(!hashToken)
        return false;
    
        const decode = jwt.decode(hashToken[1]);
    return decode;
}
```

```
//component

...

import { isAuthenticated, getUser } from '../../services/auth'

interface User {
    uid: number,
    data: {
        id: number,
        username: string,
        nome_completo: string,
        avatar: string,
        role: string
    }
}

function Topbar () {
    
     
    const user: User = getUser();

    return(
       <p> {user.uid} </p>
);
```

Comment: "I can't access" --- this needs further clarification.

Comment: You need to be returning the right type from your `getUser` function.  Also `getUser` will return `false` if there is no token, so you cannot assign `const user: User = getUser();` without checking that it's an actual user and not `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple potential points of failure here which need to be handled.  Even with proper typing, you will not be able to simply assign `const user: User = getUser();` because **`getUser` will not always return a valid user**.  You're already written that it returns `boolean false` if there is no token.  There will be an uncaught error on decoding `hashToken[1]` if there was no space in the `tokenBearer` since it would have length `1` (did you mean `hashToken[0]`?).  And, depending on the setup of your app and what `getToken()` does, there's a possibility that the decoded object is something other than a `User`.  The return type of `jwt.decode` says that it can return `null` or `string` in addition to a keyed object.

My personal design strategy would be to declare that `getUser` will either return a `User` or throw an `Error`.  Then you can wrap it in a `try/catch` block in `TopBar`.

```
const isUser = (user: any): user is User => {
    return typeof user === "object" && "uid" in user && "data" in user;
}

export const getUser = (): User => {

    const tokenBearer = getToken();
    if (!tokenBearer) {
        throw new Error("no token found");
    }

    const hashToken = tokenBearer.split(' ');
    if (!hashToken[1]) {
        throw new Error("invalid token length");
    }

    const decode = jwt.decode(hashToken[1]);
    if (!isUser(decode)) {
        throw new Error("invalid token object");
    }
    return decode;
}

function Topbar() {
    try {
        const user = getUser();
        return (
            <p>{user.uid}</p>
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return null;
        // but maybe return a login component instead of null
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/qWJ0kN)

If you have multiple components which access `getUser`, you want to isolate the logic for catching invalid responses somewhere else and separate your display logic into components like `RenderTopBar` which require that a `User` be passed in as a prop.

In this case, we could also `catch` by providing a dummy `user` or `uid` variable since we are only accessing `user.uid`.

```
function Topbar() {
    let uidString = "";
    try {
        const user = getUser();
        uidString = user.uid.toString();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

    return (
        <p>{uidString}</p>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi Linda. Thanks for your help. It's working and finally i can access the object jwt decoded.

In your code comment, you had asked about hashToken, and in fact it would be [1], because in my localstorage, I am setting "Bearer asdjfpojweiepf". In that case, I just got jwt, without the "Bearer".